# BigQuery Loading .txt file in to a table using bq load function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is it possible to load a .txt file with delimiter "|"
I use the following bq load function to load csv at the moment

```
bq --location=australia-southeast1 load --allow_jagged_rows --skip_leading_rows=1 --source_format=CSV dataset.TABLE1 gs://load_files/Test/File.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bq` supports specifying delimiter via command line arguments. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference

The option to look out for is `field_delimiter`

So, try

```
bq --location=australia-southeast1 load --field_delimiter="|" --allow_jagged_rows --skip_leading_rows=1 --source_format=CSV dataset.TABLE1 gs://load_files/Test/File.csv
```